# Astro 2.0 on AWS Amplify

Tags: node.js, aws-amplify, astrojs

I'm trying to use the SSR with AWS Amplify but when I activate the Node.js and change the output type to server. When I deploy to server I got an 404 error page.

I tried to build the project and I have to run two npm commands: npm run build and after that the npm run server. But the deploy is not working.

```
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
    postBuild:
      commands:
        - npm run server
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: /dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Astro has, adapters for each SSR cloud solution, and I haven't seen AWS listed

you could use vercel or cloudflare

and install the adapter of those server

```
npx astro add cloudflare
```

on your option I think amplify is needing for nodejs adapter and its already exist
use this instead

```
npx astro add node
```